# Stack plots generated in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plots.jl

I am running an `if` loop and want to stack the resulting plots in a grid. This is my sample code, which generates two random variables and plots a third one under two conditions:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate 10 realizations of the uniform distribution between -1 and 1 for x and y
x = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=10)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=10)

# Create empty list to store valid plots
valid_plots = []

# Initialize an empty list to store the current row of plots
current_row = []

# Loop through each realization of x and y
for i in range(len(x)):
    # Check if both x and y are positive
    if x[i] > 0 and y[i] < 0:
        # Generate 100 values of z
        z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
        # Compute the function z = xy*z^2
        z_func = x[i] * y[i] * z*z
        # Plot the function
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.plot(z, z_func)
        # If there are now two plots in the current row, append the row to valid_plots and start a new row
        if len(current_row) % 2 == 1:
            valid_plots.append(current_row)
            current_row = []
        # Append the current plot to the current row
        current_row.append(ax)
# If there is only one plot in the last row, append the row to valid_plots
if len(current_row) > 0 and len(current_row) % 2 == 1:
    current_row.append(plt.gca())
    valid_plots.append(current_row)

# Create a figure with subplots for each valid plot
num_rows = len(valid_plots)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, 2, figsize=(12, 4 * num_rows))
for i, row in enumerate(valid_plots):
    for j, ax in enumerate(row):
        # Check if the plot has any lines before accessing ax.lines[0]
        if len(ax.lines) > 0:
            axes[i, j].plot(ax.lines[0].get_xdata(), ax.lines[0].get_ydata())
plt.show()
```

The problem with the ouput is that it generates two empty graphs and  then starts stacking up vertically:

[image: output]

Could help me out? I would also be interested in more efficient methods of achieving this result.

Comment: For me, I get some graphs vertically one below the other (from your first loop where you are doing `ax.plot(z, z_func)`) and then the pic you showed me (Nx2) graphs (from `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)`). Can you explain what the expectation from this is? What do you expect to see in terms of graphs?

Comment: Thanks Redox. I expect to see only 2x2 graphs with content (no empty ones). And at most one graph that is unpaired. Essentially I want each realization to be stored and displayed in a stacked fashion once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I have understood, you are getting a random number of plots and you want to plot only those where `x[i]>0 and y[i]<0` for each pair of x and y. You don't want any blank plots either.

In your implementation, the main issue is that you are creating all the plots first and then trying to do a Nx2 plots. So, please refer to below code. I have first checked all the pairs where `x[i]>0 and y[i]<0` and collected the index alone in an array called `valid_ids`.... not plotting anything yet.

Then, as we know how many subplots are required from `len(valid_ids)`, I am plotting it in one for loop. Note that `math.ceil()` will give me the ceiling of the number of plots by 2, so we get 2 rows for 4 plots or 3 rows for 5 plots. This way, we end up plotting all the `z`s as subplots in one shot. Finally, if there is an odd number of subplots, you can use `fig.delaxes()` to remove the extra plot. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate 10 realizations of the uniform distribution between -1 and 1 for x and y
x = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=10)
y = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=10)

valid_ids=[]
for i, (j, k) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    if j > 0 and k < 0:
        valid_ids.append(i)

import math
num_rows=math.ceil(len(valid_ids)/2)

if len(valid_ids) > 0: ## No rows, don't plot anything 
    if len(valid_ids) > 2: ## More than one row, plot as axes[row, col]
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, 2, figsize=(12, 4 * num_rows))
        for i in range(len(valid_ids)):
            # Generate 100 values of z
            z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
            # Compute the function z = xy*z^2
            z_func = x[valid_ids[i]] * y[valid_ids[i]] * z*z
            # Plot the function
            axes[int(i/2), i%2].plot(z, z_func)
        # If ODD number of plots, then remove the last blank plot    
        if len(valid_ids)%2 == 1:
            fig.delaxes(axes[num_rows-1,1])
    else: ## Single row, plot as axes[col] 
        fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, 2, figsize=(12, 4))
        for i in range(len(valid_ids)):
            # Generate 100 values of z
            z = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
            # Compute the function z = xy*z^2
            z_func = x[valid_ids[i]] * y[valid_ids[i]] * z*z
            # Plot the function
            axes[i].plot(z, z_func)
        # If just one plot, then remove the second one
        if len(valid_ids) == 1:
            fig.delaxes(axes[1])
        
    plt.show()
```

**Output plot - 3 plots in my case...**

[image]